# C# - Find all the parent categories of based on selected child category

Tags: c#, parent-child

I have below class having parent child relationship. A category can have N number of Children and each of child can have N number of children and so on.

```
public class Category
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<Category> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I have populated treeview using below code.

```
        Category cat1 = new Category ;
        cat1.Id = "1";
        cat1.Name = "test1";
        this.ecrCategories.Add(cat1);

        Category cat2 = new Category ;
        cat2.Id = "2";
        cat2.Name = "test2";
        this.ecrCategories.Add(cat2);

        Category cat3 = new Category ;
        cat3.Id = "3";
        cat3.Name = "test3";
        this.ecrCategories.Add(cat3);

        Category child2 = new Category ;
        child2.Id = "6";
        child2.Name = "child2";

        Category child1 = new Category ;
        child1.Children = new List<Category>();
        child1.Id = "4";
        child1.Name = "child1";
        child1.Children.Add(child2);

        Category cat4 = new Category ;
        cat4.Children = new List<Category>();
        cat4.Id = "5";
        cat4.Name = "test5";
        cat4.Children.Add(child1);
        this.ecrCategories.Add(cat4);
```

The requirement is to find all the parents where any category is selected. Let us assume child3 category is located at test->test1->child2->child3. When child3 is clicked, i should be able to identify test,test1,child2 categories. Need to find all the parent categories of any child category selected. Pls help in achieving the same.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code provider website. Do some research on how to achieve this and if you get stuck on a particular problem, you're more than welcome to post your specific problem here. For now, this question might get closed as Too Broad.

Comment: Find all parents from where? A single Category doesn't have any reference to a parent node.

Comment: I would add a parent category to your Category Class to make it easy to find ancestors.

Comment: Yep, how  jdweng allready said. I would add a nullable int property called "parentId" to your model wich gets the id of the parent or null if it is the parent. thats a simple way for assignment.

Answer (score 0):

First of all the syntax is not correct in the provided example.

To answer your question you can do this using a `recursive` function. Here is a dummy example on how to do it:

Here I'm selecting `child2`

```
{
   //this is the main method.

   //Assuming 'ecrCategories' is list of Categories
   getparent(child2, ecrCategories);
   Console.WriteLine(str.Trim(','));
}

static string str = "";

static void getparent(Category cat, List<Category> listtocheck )
{
    foreach (var item in listtocheck)
    {
        if (item.Children == null) continue;
        if (item.Children.Count>0  )
        {
            str += item.Name + ",";
            getparent(item, item.Children);
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
test5,child1
```

Check it on [Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2ij3PD)